# Transient generator simulation torque fluctuation (Ansys Maxwell)

Tags: motor, simulation, brushless-dc-motor, transient, pmsm

while simulation for a PM axial flux generator at no load 1000RPM in Ansys Maxwell, shows moving torque fluctuating between -0.7 to 0.7 Nm, which should have been 0, as there is no load attached and it is coreless design so no cogging torque as well. Need someone to help me out.

I am working on an axial flux generator design, I consists of 2 rotors and one stator, there are 6 pole pairs and 9 coils. Here is my simulation setup

[image: image.png]

The three phase windings are connected in star configuration through Maxwell circuit.

I created two bands enclosing each rotor and then united them to assign a single band for both rotor which is set to rotational motion at 1000RPM constant. I am getting satisfactory results for output voltages, what I don't understand is this torque curve

[image]

currently the stator material is air ( I switched to air after setting it initially to electrical steel laminated, which resulted in 2Nm peaks in torque).

I don't understand the reason for this torque as there is no core so no cogging torque and also there is no load connected.

I am stuck, Kindly help :(

Comment: What is the rotor flux path? You have PM without any steel to close the path.

Comment: are there any ferrous components in the stator?

Comment: Two questions: what are material is the grey material. Is this a magnetic material such as steeI? What elements are you selecting to solve for virtual torque? Otherwise I agree with @MarkoBuršič response. I have found that coreless designs can be challenging for the FEM solutions to handle. The coreless design is far from optimal.